# no me instala chatterboot, existe otra manera o algo mas conveniente?

Tags: pycharm, inteligencia-artificial

[![Nose como soluciar este problema, ya me instale Microsoft C++ Build Tools ,chatterbot 2 ya que el chatterobot aparentemente solo hasta la vercion .8 de python.estos son los paquetes que estan en la maquina virtual.
Package         Version

---

ChatterBot2     1.1.0a7
mathparse       0.1.2
pip             22.3.1
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2023.3.post1
setuptools      65.5.1
six             1.16.0
SQLAlchemy      1.3.24[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
wheel           0.38.4
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBlEG.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBlEG.png)

Comment: Package         Version
--------------- ------------
ChatterBot2     1.1.0a7
mathparse       0.1.2
pip             22.3.1
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2023.3.post1
setuptools      65.5.1
six             1.16.0
SQLAlchemy      1.3.24
wheel           0.38.4

Comment: Package         Version
ChatterBot2     1.1.0a7
mathparse       0.1.2
pip             22.3.1
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2023.3.post1
setuptools      65.5.1
six             1.16.0
SQLAlchemy      1.3.24
wheel           0.38.4